# Unity display best times

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer

I'm a beginner to Unity and looking for some help. I've made a simple game where you try to complete a few levels as fast as possible. I have a timer script which I want to use to save the best times in a table on the main menu. I've looked at some solutions with playerprefs but I'm still kinda lost and would be very thankful if someone could guide me through this.

Timer script:

```
public class Timercontroller : MonoBehaviour
```

{

```
public Text timeCounter;

public TimeSpan timePlaying;
public bool timerGoing;
public float elapsedTime;


public void Awake()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
}


void Start()
{
    timeCounter.text = "Time: 00:00.00";
    timerGoing = false;
    BeginTimer();
    
}

public void BeginTimer()
{
    timerGoing = true;
    elapsedTime = 0f;
    StartCoroutine(UpdateTimer());

}

public void EndTimer()
{
    timerGoing = false;

}

public IEnumerator UpdateTimer()
{
    while (timerGoing)
    {
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        timePlaying = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(elapsedTime);
        string timePlayingString = "Time: " + timePlaying.ToString("mm':'ss'.'ff");
        timeCounter.text = timePlayingString;

        yield return null;

    }

}

void Update()
{
    int currentSceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
         if (currentSceneIndex == 5) {
        EndTimer();
             }
 
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for advice on saving the timers?
So, assuming your code is correct and you're just looking to save/load times, I'd do something like the following:

```
List<float> bestTimes = new List<float>();
int totalScores = 5; // the total times you want to save


/// <summary>
///  Call this in Awake to load in your data.
///  It checks to see if you have any saved times and adds them to the list if you do.
/// </summary>
public void LoadTimes() {
    for (int i = 0; i < totalScores; i++) {
        string key = "time" + i;
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey(key)) {
            bestTimes.Add(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(key));
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Call this from your EndTimer method. 
/// This will check and see if the time just created is a "best time".
/// </summary>
public void CheckTime(float time) {
    // if there are not enough scores in the list, go ahead and add it
    if (bestTimes.Count < totalScores) {
        bestTimes.Add(time);

        // make sure the times are in order from highest to lowest
        bestTimes.Sort((a, b) => b.CompareTo(a));
        SaveTimes();
    } else {

        for (int i = 0; i < bestTimes.Count; i++) {
            // if the time is smaller, insert it
            if (time < bestTimes[i]) {
                bestTimes.Insert(i, time);

                // remove the last item in the list
                bestTimes.RemoveAt(bestTimes.Count - 1);
                SaveTimes();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// This is called from CheckTime().
/// It saves the times to PlayerPrefs.
/// </summary>
public void SaveTimes() {
    for (int i = 0; i < bestTimes.Count; i++) {
        string key = "time" + i;
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(key, bestTimes[i]);
    }
}
```

I haven't gotten a chance to test this, but it seems like it would work to me.

To update the text on the highscores list, assuming they are all text objects, I'd create a new script, add it to each Text object, and add the following to the code:

```
private void Awake(){
    int index = transform.SetSiblingIndex();
    Text theText = GetComponent<Text>().text;
    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey(index)) {
        theText = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(index).ToString();
    }else{
        theText = "0";
    }
}
```

I didn't format the text above, but that's a small adjustment.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to work and isn't giving any errors so far. But how can I actually get the scores to show up on my High score list in the main menu?

Comment: I updated my respond to include my suggestion.